# How to select last names of these boxers that never lost a fight?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g

I know that my question is very strange but I have no idea how select should look in oracle if I want to see all boxers last names that never lost a fight.

So I have:

- table "boxer" with columns: id, fname, lname, weight.
- table "fight" with two foreign keys from table boxer (id_boxer1 and id_boxer2) and with one column winner (if boxer1 won then winner will be number 1, if boxer2 won then winner will be number 2)

How do I select boxers that never loose a fight in oracle?
I have oracle 11g Express Edition. (No i can't update, my professor said that my anwers should work on 11g).

I am sorry if my question does not meet the conditions of this page.

EDIT:

Thanks to your help I achieve this:

```
select b.lname
from boxer b
where 
    not exists (
        select 1 
        from fight f 
        where (f.id_boxer1 = b.id and winner = 2) or (f.id_boxer2 = b.id and winner = 1)
    )
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from fight f  
        where (f.id_boxer1 = b.id and winner = 1) or (f.id_boxer2 = b.id and winner = 2)
    )
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from fight f
        where (f.id_boxer1 = b.id and winner = 0) or (f.id_boxer2 = b.id and winner= 0)
    )
```

Comment: What does your attempted SQL look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use not exists:

```
select b.*
from boxer b
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from fight f 
    where (f.id_boxer_1 = b.id and f.winner = 2) or (f.id_boxer_2 = b.id and f.winner = 1)
)
```

If you wanted boxers that fought at least once *and* never lost:

```
select b.*
from boxer b
where 
    not exists (
        select 1 
        from fight f 
        where (f.id_boxer_1 = b.id and f.winner = 2) or (f.id_boxer_2 = b.id and f.winner = 1)
    )
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from fight f 
        where (f.id_boxer_1 = b.id and f.winner = 1) or (f.id_boxer_2 = b.id and f.winner = 2)
    )
```

Comment: Thank you it works :D. What about if i have also numer 0 when its draw

Comment: It very good because it doesn't show me boxers that never fought!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a `case` expression to get the losing boxer from the `fight` table, and then query the `boxer` table with a `not exists` operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   boxer b
WHERE  NOT EXIST (SELECT *
                  FROM   fight
                  WHERE  b.id = CASE winner WHEN 1 THEN id_boxer2 
                                            WHEN 2 THEN id_boxer1
                                END)
```

Note - if `winner=0` (i.e., neither boxer won), the can expression will return `null`, which can never be equal to `b.id`.

Comment: sorry, i forgot. I also have number 0 when it is draw.

Comment: @tadziuuuuu Thanks for the update. I updated my answer accordingly.